# Can't Save SQLİte while ImageBox.Source == null in WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, sqlite, save

I am trying to save my datas to sqlite also my datas have photo.
I want to save the datas with photo or without photo.
when I add photo, I can save it to sqlite. but when imagebox.Source is null, it gives error :

> 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'

and it shows error in :

```
public byte[] BitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource image)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); // or some other encoder
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Here is my codes:

```
    private void SaveButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

            if (ImageBox.Source != null)
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                image.UriSource = new Uri(filephoto.FileName);
                image.EndInit();
                ImageBox.Source = image;
            }

            helper.DataSave("CompanyData", CInfo, image);
       }
```

In helper class, DataSave;

```
    public bool DataSave(string TableName, CustomerInfo CInfox, BitmapImage obj) // Save to DataBase
    {
        //try
        //{
            ConOpen();
            string query = $"Insert Into {TableName} (Company, Product, Product_No, Product_Size, Photo) Values (@company, @product, @pno, @psize, @photo)";
            SQLiteCommand komut = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);

            SQLiteParameter param1 = new SQLiteParameter("@company", DbType.String);
            SQLiteParameter param2 = new SQLiteParameter("@product", DbType.String);
            SQLiteParameter param3 = new SQLiteParameter("@pno",     DbType.String);
            SQLiteParameter param4 = new SQLiteParameter("@psize",   DbType.String);
            SQLiteParameter param5 = new SQLiteParameter("@photo",   DbType.Binary);

            param1.Value = CInfox.Customer;
            param2.Value = CInfox.Product;
            param3.Value = CInfox.ProductNo;
            param4.Value = CInfox.ProductSize;
            param5.Value = BitmapSourceToByteArray(obj);


            komut.Parameters.Add(param1);
            komut.Parameters.Add(param2);
            komut.Parameters.Add(param3);
            komut.Parameters.Add(param4);
            komut.Parameters.Add(param5);

            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Succesfully!");
            ConClose();
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that you have this settings in config file `<configuration> <appSettings> <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1000" /> </appSettings> </configuration>`

Comment: Does the column that will hold the image data in your database allow null values? If so, you may need to handle the null values in some way. Also, you will probably want to wrap your entire database transaction in a Try/Catch/Finally block to ensure that the database connection is always closed.

Comment: @joshman1019 yet it is allowed.  I keep trying but result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your database will accept null values, you may want to refactor:

```
    public bool DataSave(string TableName, CustomerInfo CInfox, BitmapImage obj) // Save to DataBase
{
    try
    {
        ConOpen();
        string query = $"Insert Into {TableName} (Company, Product, Product_No, Product_Size) Values (@company, @product, @pno, @psize)";
        SQLiteCommand komut = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);

        SQLiteParameter param1 = new SQLiteParameter("@company", DbType.String);
        SQLiteParameter param2 = new SQLiteParameter("@product", DbType.String);
        SQLiteParameter param3 = new SQLiteParameter("@pno",     DbType.String);
        SQLiteParameter param4 = new SQLiteParameter("@psize",   DbType.String);

        param1.Value = CInfox.Customer;
        param2.Value = CInfox.Product;
        param3.Value = CInfox.ProductNo;
        param4.Value = CInfox.ProductSize;

        komut.Parameters.Add(param1);
        komut.Parameters.Add(param2);
        komut.Parameters.Add(param3);
        komut.Parameters.Add(param4);

        if(obj is not null) // if(obj != null) for older C# versions
        {
            string query = $"Insert Into {TableName} (Company, Product, Product_No, Product_Size, Photo) Values (@company, @product, @pno, @psize, @photo)";
            SQLiteParameter param5 = new SQLiteParameter("@photo",   DbType.Binary);
            param5.Value = BitmapSourceToByteArray(obj);
            komut.Parameters.Add(param5);
        }

        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Succesfully!");

   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
        // Handle exceptions here or let it bubble up to caller (You should use transactions)
   }
   finally
   {
        ConClose();
   }
        return true;
}
```

Additional info. Helpers for image conversion

```
    internal static class SignatureImageConversion
{
    public static BitmapImage ConvertFileToBitmap(this string path)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri(path);
        image.EndInit();
        return image; 
    }

    public static BitmapImage ConvertFileStreamToBitmap(this byte[] stream)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(stream);
        image.EndInit();
        return image; 
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(this BitmapImage image)
    {
        byte[] data = null; 
        JpegBitmapEncoder jpencoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        jpencoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            jpencoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this code but when I click the save button, there is no reaction. no error, no database info, nothing.

Comment: If you are calling some dialog box or another UI based message source, it may not display because these events are not on the UI thread.

Comment: okey I did, but the same error gives again.

Comment: When you inspect the code at a breakpoint, is obj actually null, or is there some other value set in obj?

Comment: I answered my post, there is a situation. it worked for a code. but it didnt worked for another code. can you check

Comment: It appears that obj may be assigned some value and it cannot be converted to a byte array properly. I see that you assigned it to null directly and the code worked, so that leads me to believe that there is some value being assigned. You will need to probably set a breakpoint and inspect it.

Comment: I used breakpoint
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sTq9.png

Comment: I have added a section of my extension helpers for bitmap images that seem to match what you are doing. Your ImageBox source may need to be set to null by default. But without seeing that part of the application, I'm not sure.

Comment: Just to note: My code, written much like yours (see my helpers section) works just fine with nulls and with images. So there may be a problem with how the image is set, and the initial state of the ImageBox on the UI layer. Or there is something missing in your conversion process.

Comment: thank you for your effort. As you said, I set initial value of image as null, it worked succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is limit on the max size that is 1000 by default, you need to increase it if you are posting large data which is to be desrialized.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2000" />
</appSettings>
```

> Setting this attribute to too large a number can pose a security risk.